# backbone.js , waiting for external post request to complete

Tags: ajax, image, post, backbone.js, upload

I have an image uploader on my index.php page, when the image starts uploading (initiated by dragging image onto upload box) , the POST request is created (FYI HTML5 + php Uploader)

```
POST http://localhost:8888/backbone_images/post_file.php
```

Inside of my post_file.php , I retrieve the URL of my uploaded image by inserting it in my exit_status, than later in my script assigning it to a global javascript variable 'globe'

```
if(move_uploaded_file($pic['tmp_name'], $upload_dir.$pic['name'])){
        exit_status($pic['name']);
    }
```

Inside of my backbone script file, I check for the drop event into the dropbox, which works,

```
App.Views.AddImage = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#addImage',  
    events: {
        'drop': 'submit' 
    },
```

so the image has been dragged onto the dropbox, and I call my submit function to create a new model
and assign the url of the new image (which I pass through a javascript variable)
to the url of my new model

```
    submit: function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();  // preventing default submission..
        var newImage = globe;  // assign globe --url of the newly created image--to new model
        var imager = new App.Models.Person({ url: newImage });//creating a new img object
        this.collection.add(imager); 
    }
```

The problem is that when my backbone submit function is triggered after an image is dropped, my POST to /post_file.php hasn't run yet, as a result my variable 'globe' doesn't contain the new URL, and my newly created model ends up lacking a url

So question: is there any way for me to wait for the POST to finish within my backbone events before executing my 'submit' function, after an image drop?

I tried to use: `$.when( $.ajax("/post_file.php") )` inside of my submit function, but all this does is run another POST request, leaves my variable value, than run the original POST request retrieving the image URL that I'm waiting for.

My preferred workflow would be

a. drag/upload image, (POST performs) 
 b. new model is added to
    collection with URL of uploaded image,

but I end having to add an additional click function first otherwise the POST doesn't finish

a. drag/upload image, (POST peforms) 
 b. click on a submit button 
 c. model is added to collection

Comment: I'd suggest creating your model elsewhere, like in the success callback for your ajax call. Otherwise, you'll need some kind of pub/sub setup (you can use Backbone.Events for this) to handle the asynchronous nature of when you need to make your model.

Comment: Hi --> so for creating a model "in the success callback for the ajax call" , how would I access the callback from my backbone script? Can you elaborate on what you mean?

Comment: shouldn't you be calling the `$.ajax('post_file')` in the submit method and doing the subsequent stuff in the success event?

Comment: @nEEbz is there a 'success' event that can be triggered in bkbone events like { 'POST:success', 'success' } I was looking for something similar but couldn't find it

Comment: just use the success event of the `$.ajax`. You could further enhance your overall code structure using Backbone.Events but the most basic premise could be that you make an ajax request to post_file in your submit handler and in the success case you create the model and add it to the collection. Also make sure your ajax returns the file url in response (instead of putting it in a global variable)